# metro encountering an error while using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

here everyone, am trying to use Firebase in my React-native project but encountering an error: Unable to resolve "idb" from "node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js, why am I having this error, is there something am doing different.

here is code

```
// firebase.js file
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { GOOGLE_CLIENT_API_KEY,GOOGLE_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN,GOOGLE_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID,GOOGLE_CLIENT_STORAGE_BUCKET,GOOGLE_CLIENT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,GOOGLE_CLIENT_APP_ID,GOOGLE_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID } from "@env"


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: GOOGLE_CLIENT_API_KEY,
    authDomain: GOOGLE_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: GOOGLE_CLIENT_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_APP_ID,
    measurementId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```